# Trigger onchange event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am triggering event on change but my code doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#category').trigger('change');
    $(document).on('change', '#category', function() {
        var type = $(this).val();
        if (type != '') {
            show_page_block_loader();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo url("/menu-manager/fetchcategory");?>',
                data: {
                    type: type
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#category_id').html(response);
                    hide_page_block_loader();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `$('#category').trigger('change');` ?

Comment: Please create a minimal reproduction by creating a snippet! Is not that complicated.

Comment: when my page load at that time i want to automatically fire change event of dropdown. so $('#category').trigger('change'); this will trigger onchange event as per me. plz correct me if i am wrong. thanks

Comment: Check my below answer. Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should trigger change the select after adding an event listener to the select like

```
  $('#category').trigger('change');
```

Put this line of code after adding the event like

```
$(document).on('change','#category', function() { ... });
```

Comment: thanks void :) Issue  Solved

Comment: unfortunately my reputation is less then 15 :)

Comment: Oh thanks for the info. done :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You are triggering the event before it binds to the control. Move `$(#category).trigger("change");` to the last. I have also change the the "Change" event initialization.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#category).change(function () {
        var type = $(this).val();
                if(type != ''){
                    show_page_block_loader();
                    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}}); 
                    $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          url: '<?php echo url("/menu-manager/fetchcategory");?>',
                          data: {type:type},
                          success: function (response) {
                            $('#category_id').html(response);
                            hide_page_block_loader();
                          }
                    });
                }

    });

    $(#category).trigger("change");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer below.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#category').change(function(){
          var type = $(this).val();
                if(type != ''){
                    show_page_block_loader();
                    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}}); 
                    $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          url: '<?php echo url("/menu-manager/fetchcategory");?>',
                          data: {type:type},
                          success: function (response) {
                            $('#category_id').html(response);
                            hide_page_block_loader();
                          }
                    });
                }

       }).trigger('change');
  });
```

Thanks,